# Adafruit ST-Link STM8/STM32 v2 can't connect to STM32F091

Tags: stm32, st-link, st, adafruit

I've an [Adafruit ST-Link STM8/STM32](https://blog.adafruit.com/2015/06/01/new-product-st-link-stm8stm32-v2-programmer-emulator/) v2 which I need to connect to an STM32F091.
The MCU is powered from an external source and I have correctly connected the SWCLK and SWDIO as well as GND and 3.3V.
The STM32CubeProgrammer correctly see the USB stick and is able to upgrade its FW but I cannot connect to it. Also, using the ST Visual Programmer or ST Link or IAR it says that it can't connect to the MCU target.

Everything works smooth with the original ST Link.

I'm using SWD connection of course

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Should you ask the product seller how to use their product?

Comment: @Justme according to their guide, this is how it should work...

Comment: They tell you to connect the 3V3 output from Adafruit product to 3V3 output from MCU board?

Comment: @Justme we tried both way, same result

Comment: Maybe it is now damaged? Power supplies should not be shorted together.

Comment: @Justme nope, with the original st-link everything works smooth, even after trying with the Adafruit stick

Comment: I meant the Adafruit stick. Maybe damaged if it does not work.

Comment: @Justme we tried 3 of them; we also measured the Vcc output voltage on every adafruit stick and it correctly measure 5V